# Issue with Mule FileMessageReceiver - WARN issues

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-el

With the following file configuration, the application consistently provides a WARN issue.  Please see below for an example of the logs.

```
WARN  2014-04-15 18:46:59,285 [[processes].accountFlow1.stage1.02] org.mule.transport.file.FileMessageReceiver: Failure trying to remove file /file/file/file.file from list of files under processing
DEBUG 2014-04-15 18:46:59,289 [[processes].accountFlow1.stage1.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: test1
DEBUG 2014-04-15 18:46:59,291 [[processes].accountFlow1.stage1.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: *******
DEBUG 2014-04-15 18:46:59,424 [[processes].accountFlow1.stage1.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: *******
DEBUG 2014-04-15 18:46:59,477 [[processes].accountFlow1.stage1.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: *******
DEBUG 2014-04-15 18:46:59,583 [[processes].accountFlow1.stage1.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: *******
DEBUG 2014-04-15 18:46:59,609 [[processes].accountFlow1.stage1.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: *******
DEBUG 2014-04-15 18:46:59,613 [[processes].accountFlow1.stage1.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: *******
DEBUG 2014-04-15 18:46:59,658 [[processes].accountFlow1.stage1.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: *******
DEBUG 2014-04-15 18:46:59,659 [[processes].accountFlow1.stage1.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: *******
DEBUG 2014-04-15 18:46:59,672 [[processes].accountFlow1.stage1.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: *******
DEBUG 2014-04-15 18:46:59,684 [[processes].accountFlow1.stage1.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: *******
DEBUG 2014-04-15 18:46:59,725 [[processes].accountFlow1.stage1.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: *******
DEBUG 2014-04-15 18:46:59,727 [[processes].accountFlow1.stage1.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: *******
DEBUG 2014-04-15 18:46:59,735 [[processes].accountFlow1.stage1.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: *******
WARN  2014-04-15 18:46:59,824 [Finalizer] org.mule.transport.file.ReceiverFileInputStream: Failed to move file from /file/file/processing/file.file to /file/file/archive/file.file
```

The connectors are setup in the following way:

```
<file:connector name="InputFileConnector" doc:name="File Connector" workDirectory="${Processing_Path}" 
            workFileNamePattern="#[message.outboundProperties['originalFilename']]" moveToDirectory="${Archive_Path}" 
            moveToPattern="#[message.outboundProperties['originalFilename']]"
            streaming="true" autoDelete="false" validateConnections="true" fileAge="${FileAge}"/>
```

Inbound-endpoint Configuration:

```
<file:inbound-endpoint responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" path="${Inbound_Path}" pollingFrequency="${PollingFrequency}" connector-ref="InputFileConnector">
            <!-- Add filename-regex-filter to insure files are there to kick off the process -->
            <file:filename-regex-filter pattern="SAMPLE\d+\.FILE" caseSensitive="true"/>
        </file:inbound-endpoint>
```

I am looking for any insights or suggestions on what is causing this WARN issue in Mule.

**Update** Change streaming attribute to false, resolves the WARN issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mule has some issues with streaming file endpoints, so you could try your app with `streaming="false"` in the connector. I don't know exactly what is going on with the Mule file streaming, but I guess it could be something like an open file handle that produces an exception when the file is removed from the processing list.

Comment: Ah gotcha, thanks. I have another question - if streaming="false" and you do a moveToPattern with a different name than the original file name, why does Mule convert the payload to a byte? 

Exception stack is: 1. Message has been rejected by filter. Message payload is of type: byte[] (org.mule.api.routing.filter.FilterUnacceptedException) org.mule.routing.MessageFilter:100 (mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/routing/…

Comment: If streaming="false", a file payload should be byte[], regardless of moveToPattern.

Comment: Odd... my processor elements are able to process the byte[] without having to transform the payload to an object or string, until I modified the original file name in the moveToPattern.  Anyways, since I'm receiving the byte[] error, I tried to transform the byte[] payload with a byte-array-to-string-transformer, but I continue to get errors that say the following... ERROR 2014-04-16 10:05:50,466 [[processes].InputFileConnector.receiver.01] org.mule.exception.CatchMessagingExceptionStrategy:
Message: Message has been rejected by filter. Message payload is of type: byte[] Code: MULE_ERROR--2

Comment: Changing the streaming="false" does resolve the original question.  Starting new question regarding moveToPattern filter causing errors.